# How to convert usb stereo microphone to two mono microphone devices

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I need to convert a usb stereo microphone into two mono devices to make it independently recognizable by **Python's pyaudio**, but so far I have been unsuccessful in my investigations.

Based on a [PulseAudio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Examples) I have inserted this into default.pa:

**load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=left_to_mono master=alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_PnP_Sound_Device-00.analog-stereo channels=2 master_channel_map=front-left channel_map=mono,mono**

**load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=right_to_mono master=alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_PnP_Sound_Device-00.analog-stereo channels=2 master_channel_map=front-right channel_map=mono,mono**

But there have been no apparent changes. With the command **pacmd list-sources** a single device appears and not two mono devices as I would like. I don't know if I have done it wrong since I have no experience with Linux. Can you help me?

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do is not possible with ANY software.

Comment: It can not be done? would there be any other way to do it? I need Python to recognize the right channel and the left channel independently.